# How to take some values from a file and store it into an array, in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to get some values from an input file using the open/read syscalls as shown below:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stddef.h>
    #include <semaphore.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <errno.h>

        #define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

        int main (int argc, const char * argv[] ){

        int inputFile;
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

        int heed;

        if (argc < 1){
            perror("There isn't any file");
            return -1;
        }
        else {
        input = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        if (inputFile < 0){
            printf("Error, execution interrupted\n");
            return -1;
        }

        inputFile = open(datos,O_RDWR);
        while((heed = read(inputFile,buffer,BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0);
    printf("The first value stored in buffer is: %s\n",buffer[0]);
}
 return 0
 }
```

When I try to print the values stored in buffer, I get values that are different from the one I write on.

```
The first value stored in buffer is: 52
```

The input file contains these values, separated by an space:

```
4 5 5 2 1 2 3 3 5 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include compilable code.

Comment: And also edit it to show where you are printing the values - I can't see that in thequestion - yet

Comment: You have a local variable called read that hides the function read. Pay heed to your compiler or post exactly the code you are compiling.

Comment: question was edited.

Comment: `if (inputFile < 0)` -- `inputFile` is uninitialized, `%s\n",buffer[0]` → `%s\n",buffer`, `if (argc < 1){` → `if (argc < 2){` (First argument is the name of the program)

Comment: @JustAsking The posted code _still_ won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fscanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  if(argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please provide file name\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  FILE *pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
  if(pFile == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "No such file\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int nBufferLen = 0;
  while(nBufferLen < BUFFER_SIZE) {
    int nRet = fscanf(pFile, "%c", &buffer[nBufferLen]);
    if(nRet == EOF) break;
    else if(nRet == 1) { /* read successfully */ }
    else {
      printf("No Match\n");
    }
    nBufferLen++;
  }
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < nBufferLen; i++)
    printf("%c ", buffer[i]);
  printf("\n");
  fclose(pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

when i run it, i can see the desired output :

```
~/Documents/src : $ gcc arrayFile.c 
~/Documents/src : $ ./a.out stuff.txt 
4   5   5   2   1   2   3   3   5   2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was usefull.